# Django1.8 and Python2.7: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-2.7

I'm using Django v1.8 in Python v2.7.

I'm trying to read data from an API I created. The response of the API is in json format.

The error I get is: `ERROR -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)` for this line of code `(var key in response['alzDysphagia'][0] )` in an ajax call.

Calling the API from browser itself, is working properly and I get the json response.

Can you help me please?

Below you can find my `views.py` code and the ajax call in my template.

views.py

```
for myfields in l_v:
        if counter ==0:
            print "counter=0"
            counter = counter +1
        elif counter !=0:
            if counter == count-1:
                myfields = '{'+myfields
                dictionary = json.loads(myfields)

                dict= {"DysphagiaComment" : dictionary["DysphagiaComment"] , "Imipaxireusta" : dictionary["Imipaxireusta"] , "Liquids":dictionary["Liquids"] , "Solid":dictionary["Solid"] }

                print "dict "
                print dict

                print "dictionary"
                # print dictionary

            else:
                counter += 1

# print form_collection
print "diction"
# print dictionary

# temp = json.dumps(dict)
temp = json.dumps({"alzDyshpagia":[dict]})
print temp

return HttpResponse(temp)
```

template html file

```
**$.ajax({
                            url: "/Dysphagia",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                                patientId: aValue,
                                Select_dys: true
                            },
                             dataType:'json',
                            async: true,
                            success: function (response){
                                console.log("response :");
                                console.log(response.type);
                                console.log("rw");
                                for (var key in response['alzDysphagia'][0] ){
{#                                    console.log(response['alzDysphagia'][0][key]);#}
                                    $('[name="' + key.toLowerCase() + '"]input[value="' + response['alzDysphagia'][0][key] + '"]').prop('checked', true)
                                    $("#" + key.toLowerCase()).val(response['alzDysphagia'][0][key]).attr('disabled',true);

                            }

                            }

                        })**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in your Python script:

`temp = json.dumps({"alzDyshpagia":[dict]})`

Should be

`temp = json.dumps({"alzDysphagia":[dict]})` (the 'p' and 'h' are reversed).